# shell_exec unable to execute on VPS

Tags: php

When using the `shell_exec` on my code in my VPS server (Linux) I get an error:

```
    Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'php /home/usr/public_html/testsite/test.php remote' in /home/usr/public_html/testsite/test2.php on line 8
```

**I striped the error, actually I get a lot of `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8` before display the Warning error.**

---

test.php:

```
function connect($server)
    {
            $servername = "localhost:3306";
            $username = "user";
            $password = "pass";
            $dbname = "dbname";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        else{
            echo 'connected';
        }

        return $conn;

    }
```

test2.php:

```
echo shell_exec('php /home/usr/public_html/testsite/test.php');
```

---

I tried with my local machine (Mac OS X) with MAMP and it worked perfectly (yes, I update the database parameters and files accordingly). I also tried system() and passthru() with no luck.

What should I change on my VPS server? Linux configuration? Apache?

Comment: The `php` executable may not be in `$PATH` on the VPS for the user executing the parent script. Try passing the full path to it, probably `/usr/bin/php` -- find out where via `which php` on the VPS.

Comment: It's also unclear what else is going on in test.php, because all you do in the posted code is define a function. It isn't called. If that script dies with a fatal error, shell_exec() will fail. Can you execute that file successfully on the VPS directly, and _without_ `shell_exec()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I make it work when add the -p right after the php word.

Answer (score 0):

PHP might not be in your path: You might be able to use [PHP_BINARY](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to find the path to PHP, but many PHP installs don't include the command-line version of PHP. This is common if using a PHP module or filter.

On Debian/Ubuntu systems you can ask for php5-cli to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

On other systems there will be a similar command.

If you aren't the system administrator, you can ask the VPS administrator for help.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the command `which php` to determine whether the php executable is accessible.

Comment: @derjoachim - I didn't recommend this because if php isn't in your path, then `which` isn't going to help, and and if PHP *is* in your path (but not httpd), then the sysadmin has made other changes.